# appending values in key/value hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to append values in hash specific to particular key and value and then sort them based on values. So here is what I am trying to do

```
 @arr = Hash.new
 $m.each do |s|
  if (s.start.hour == check.hour)
    if params[:type] == 'A'
      s.As.each do |w|
          @arr['name'].push((w.name))
          @arr['id'].push((w.id).to_i)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It is obvious that I will get only last value but I could not find out how to append these values for this hash. 
Not much familiar with ruby so help appreciated on this and some idea how to sort the created hash with respect to `'id's  in @arr`

Links that I have already tried [1](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/112072) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766877/ruby-inserting-key-value-elements-in-hash)

Comment: a comment on of the linked to questions is relevant here: `What result are you getting? In such a question it is helpful if you include "I expected result <X> but got result <Y>"`

Comment: Why are you appending to two arrays in the Hash? If you need the hash sorted by `id` why not use `id` as the key and add values to that?

Comment: actually I am trying to do the same but have no idea how to do as it was very easy in javascript

Comment: that didn't answer my question.  what result are you getting now?

Comment: I get this now {"id":[3],"name":["Abc"]}

Comment: and what do you want to get?

Comment: I want all the id and name in @arr, where currently I have this last value.

Comment: I believe that I can sort arr with id's  once I have all the values in @arr

Comment: Please don't use the variable name `@arr` to refer to a Hash. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirements, you are using the Hash in way that makes more work later. Your current data structure will look like this:

```
{ 
  id:   [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  name: [ a, b, c ] 
}
```

Which means you have to use arrays and indexes to sort and line up the `id` and `name`.

Hash's support what you are trying to achieve out of the box if you restructure it to use the `id` as a key:

```
{ 
  1: { name: a },
  2: { name: b },
  3: { name: c }
}
```

To do this you can assign values to the Hash in your loop like so:

```
@arr[w.id.to_i] = { "name" => w.name }
```

Then your Hash can be accessed, in order with:

```
@arr.sort.map do |id, value|
  # work with id and value["name"]
end
```

Reiterating what Mark Thomas noted, use a meaningful name for the Hash instead of `@arr` as that only adds confusion.

Comment: +1.  good solution.  using meaningful names for all the variables would be nice, in fact..

Comment: true that! `@arr` is particularly bad though :/